# what code-instrument should be added to register each http event in MeterRegistry with specific tag & minute value. Event requests are in millions

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

**I need to analyse one http event value which should not be greater than 30mins. & 95% event should belong to this bucket. If it fails send the alert.**

My first concern is to get the right metrics in /actuator/prometheus

***Steps I took:***
As in every http request event, I am getting one integer value called eventMinute.

Using ***micrometer MeterRegistry***, I tried below code

```
// MeterRegistry meterRegistry ...
meterRegistry.summary("MINUTES_ANALYSIS", tags);
```

> where *tag = EVENT_MINUTE* which receives some integer value in each
> http event.
>
> But this way, it floods the metrics due to millions of event.

*Guide me a way please, i am beginner to this. Thanks!!*

Comment: Is your goal to count how many request are coming in? And if the specific endpoint is receiving fewer than 95% of the traffic you want to alert?

Comment: Actually in every http request, I am getting one field which is carrying an integer value. That value may be different in every call so i have to send that value to meter-registry instrument.. later using prometheus based on that integer value, i have to analyse how many request brought value greater than 30
and then out of whole request if at least 95% of request value not fall in less than 30. 
Than send alert. Thanks!!

Comment: meterRegistry.summary(metricName, tags).record(intValue);
this i recently tried getting metrics, would that be a good way or i should use any slo sla min max value for the same

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution (which I would recommend you start with) would be to just create 2 counters:

```java
int theThing = //getTheThing()
if(theThing > 30) {
  meterRegistry.counter("my.request.counter.abovethreshold").inc()
} 
meterRegistry.counter("my.request.counter.total").inc()
```

You would increment the counter that matches your threshold and another that tracks all requests (or reuse another meter that does that for you).

Then it is simple to setup a chart or alarm:

```
my_request_counter_abovethreshold/my_request_counter_total < .95
```

(I didn't test the code. It might need a tiny bit of tweaking)

You'll be able to do a similar thing with `DistributionSummary` by setting various SLOs (I'm not familiar with them to be able to offer one), but start with something simple first and if it is sufficient, you won't need the other complexity.

Comment: your solution really make sense Thanks!! but i want to do it with DistributionSummary actually.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain ways to solve this problem

> 1 ; here is a function which receives tags, name of metrics and a value

```
public void createOrUpdateHistogram(String metricName, Map<String, String> stringTags, double numericValue)
     {   
                DistributionSummary.builder(metricName)
                    .tags(tags)
                   //can enforce slo if required
                        .publishPercentileHistogram()
                        .minimumExpectedValue(1.0D) // can take this based on how you want your distibution
                        .maximumExpectedValue(30.0D)
                        .register(this.meterRegistry)
                        .record(numericValue);
        }
```

then it produce metrics like

> delta_bucket{mode="CURRENT",le="30.0",} 11.0
>
> delta_bucket{mode="CURRENT", le="+Inf",} 11.0

so as infinte also hold the less than value, so subtract the le=30 from le=+Inf

Another ways could be

```
       public void createOrUpdateHistogram(String metricName, Map<String, String> stringTags, double numericValue)
  {    
         Timer.builder(metricName)
         .tags(tags)
         .publishPercentiles(new double[]{0.5D, 0.95D})
         .publishPercentileHistogram()
         .serviceLevelObjectives(new Duration[]{Duration.ofMinutes(30L)})
         .minimumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMinutes(30L))
         .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMinutes(30L))
         .register(this.meterRegistry)
         .record((long)timeDifference, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
     }
```

it will only have two le, the given time and +inf

it can be change based on our requirements also it gives us quantile.